# recommendation on books that specializes in inequality(self-study)

Tags: inequality, book-recommendation, advice

I am a student in the second year of university, I study calculus (self -study) through "calculus " by Spivak, and frankly I liked the approach of this book, in parallel with that, I spend my free time trying to prove some of the inequalities that I find on this site or anywhere ( For me, proving the inequality is an entertaining game), my knowledge of the tools used in the inequality is very limited, so I want to learn some of the tools and theories that are used in this subject, so is there a book that specializes in them and studies them in detail?, it would be better if the approach of this book is like approach of of Spivak.

any recommendation,advice,and comment are welcom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best go is:

Steele's "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities".

The title says it all. It is a highly recommended and pedagogical book. Most importantly, since you mention you do self-study, the solutions to all the exercises are in the back of the book.

Comment: in order to get started with this book 'Do I have to be fluent in calculus, because I'm still studying calculus

Comment: @anaas I would say yes, you will see concepts as series, integrals and derivatives in this book. I think you should have an ok understanding of calculus before tackling it. Some nice extras to have before (although I wouldn't say necessary) are a tiny bit of probability and a tiny bit of linear algebra. Good luck!

Comment: so i must finish my study in calculus before starting with this book?

Comment: @anaas I would think so, yes.

Comment: thank you sir..

Comment: @anaas No problem. I would still advise you to check out the first pages using google preview and see how comfortable you feel with the book. You might be able to tackle some parts of the book without full knowledge of calculus. Although to be able to get the most out of the whole book, you will need to finish studying calculus first. :)

Comment: Yes, I saw some pages of the book, and decided to study through it  after finishing calculus

Answer (score 2):

Like the classic book "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class: An Introduction to the Art of Mathematical Inequalities", you can also find $ 1)$ and $2) $  interesting

1 ) An Introduction to Inequalities
Edwin Beckenbach, Richard Bellman ( [Review](https://bookstore.ams.org/nml-3/) )

2 ) Algebraic Inequalities: New Vistas
[MAA Review](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/algebraic-inequalities-new-vistas)

Comment: in order to get started with this books 'Do I have to be fluent in calculus, because I'm still studying calculus?

Comment: Nothing beyond high school algebra is required of the student. The exposition is lean " - From the Author (2).

Comment: I think you can study those books along with calculus.